# $L^1$ norm submultiplicative?

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lp-spaces

Let $f,g:[0,1]\to[0,M]$ be measurable for some $M<\infty$. We know by the Hoelder inequality that for any $p\geq1$, $$\|fg\|_1\leq\|f\|_p\|g\|_{1/(1-1/p)}\,.$$

Do we also have (for this special case of bounded functions on bounded domains) that $\|\cdot\|_1$ is actually submultiplicative, that is, $$\|fg\|_1\leq\|f\|_1\|g\|_1\,??$$

Here is a suggested proof for which I don't immediately see the problem:
\begin{align*}
\|fg\|_1 & \equiv \int_{[0,1]}fg \\
& = \int_{[0,1]^2}f(x)g(y)\delta(x-y)~\mathrm dx~\mathrm d y.
\end{align*}

Now since as measures on $[0,1]^2$, $\delta(x-y)~\mathrm dx~\mathrm d y\leq\mathrm dx~\mathrm d y$, we find (using Fubini's theorem) the claim.

Comment: Your $\delta(x-y)$ means you are using the counting measure on the diagonal, which is not be $\sigma$-finite, so Fubini doesn't apply.

Comment: To be clear, your estimate of the measure does not hold, and this has nothing to do with sigma finiteness (you are not using a counting measure but the Hausdorff measure on the diagonal, which is sigma finite, even finite in the normal sense)

Comment: Is there any way to understand the fault with the measure estimate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any set $E$ with $0<m(E)<1$ and take $f=g=I_E$. Then $\|fg\|_1=m(E)$ and $\|f\|_1\|g\|_1=m(E)^{2}$. But $m(E)^{2} <m(E)$.